# How to generate a random number from an array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate a random SKU number from the array. Using Math.floor() and Math.random() to get the index. But it only returns a letter or number instead of the entire string. Here is the function:

```
function bookRentData(bookData) {

   bookData.forEach((book) => {

      //generate random sku number

      const sku = book.sku
      var random = sku[Math.floor(Math.random() * sku.length - 1)];
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = sku[random];   

      });
        wrap.innerHTML += `<tr>
                             <td>${book.sku}</td>
                             <td>${book.price}</td>
                          </tr>`
   }
```

expected output: `101ZS536`

current output: `Z`

```
// example of the data 

         [{sku: '101ZS536',
            price: 4.37
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 42.61
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 53.31
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 0
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 3.46
          }
        ]
```

Any advice or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `bookData`? Why do you use `.forEach()`? What is `book.sku`/`sku`? If you answer all those questions you should find the source of your problem.

Comment: Its returning `z` because `sku` value is set equal to `[1,0,1,Z,S,5,3,6]`. i.e. the value of `book.sku`

Comment: @Andreas `bookData` holds the entire data, `.forEach()` goes over each object in the data and `book.sku` returns each book sku number from each object. I am trying to retrieve 1 of those sku numbers randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple and readable answer that uses [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) to access a random value from the array and then accesses the sku of that object:

```js
var arr = [
  {sku: '123ZS536', price: 4.37},
  {sku: '45634ABC', price: 42.61},
  {sku: '10134DEF', price: 53.31},
  {sku: '78934GHI', price: 0},
  {sku: '10134QYT', price: 3.46}
];

console.log( rando(arr).value.sku );
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

If you want to use this code, don't forget to put that script tag in the head of your html document.

Answer (score 1):

Check this satisfies your scenario.

```js
function bookRentData() {
var bookData =  [{sku: '101ZS536',
            price: 4.37
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 42.61
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QXT',
            price: 53.31
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QZT',
            price: 0
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QST',
            price: 3.43
          },
           {
            sku: '10134QCT',
            price: 3.46
          },
           {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 3.1
          },
           {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 3.2
          },
           {
            sku: '10134QBT',
            price: 3.6
          },
           {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 3.5
          },
          {
            sku: '10134QJT',
            price: 3.1
          },
           {
            sku: '10134QYT',
            price: 3.2
          },
           {
            sku: '10134QRT',
            price: 3.6
          },
           {
            sku: '10134QKT',
            price: 3.5
          }
          
        ];
   book = bookData[Math.floor(Math.random() * bookData.length)]
   var x = document.getElementById("demo")
   x.innerHTML = book.sku;
       
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Test</p>

<button onclick="bookRentData()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns an entire object. I am only trying to retrieve the SKU number from the array of objects. In this case, `10134QYT`.  Later, I will update the price.

Comment: You can take the SKU number from the object, right? Check the updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```js
function bookRentData(bookData) {
   book = bookData[Math.floor(Math.random() * bookData.length - 1)]

        wrap.innerHTML += `<tr>
                             <td>${book.sku}</td>
                             <td>${book.price}</td>
                          </tr>`
}
```

I assume you want a single `sku` from the list as you need a random one. (And if you want all then no need for them to be random.)

PS comment if I didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: this returns the entire object. I am just trying to get the SKU number. Thanks!

Comment: Yup `book` is an object but your inner html will have the no. only as it's `book.sku`

Answer (score 0):

You have `Math.floor(Math.random() * sku.length - 1)`, which might sometimes return `-1`.

To generate a number between 0 to length, you can change to:

```
      var random = sku[Math.floor(Math.random() * sku.length)];
```